# Double back slashes escape code formatting in comments (but not answers)

Tags: bug, comments, design, code-formatting, inline-code

I recently posted on answer on Stack Overflow which mentioned the discrepancy between windows and linux path separators in the answer. I enclosed both in inline code snippets like so: `\\` and `/`. These render fine, both in the editor, and in the answer itself.

However, when I commented a similar remark on the answer (to ping the asker about the important discrepancy), the code formatting did not work. I eventually had to run the two together, because the backtick at the end would not close the first code snippet. (see comment section of this answer for an example).

For the record, when I type the inline code snippets (seen above), I write

```
`\\` and `/`
```

-exactly as show above. This is also exactly what I type in the comment below this post.

It appears that the way to get this code to format correct in the comments is to use double backticks on the first code block, as so:

```
``\\``
```

This also works fine in the answer and editor itself: `\\`, however the discrepancy of rendering the original snippet in questions/answer/editor vs a comment should still be considered a bug in my opinion.

Comment: Example comment: `\\` and `/`

Comment: Does 3 back slashes work?  or 4 `\\\\`

Comment: It appears double backtics does the trick ``\\``